# Why would a triggered webjob go to aborted state?

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a triggered webjob, which is invoked by the Scheduler (Azure) every 5 mins. I have WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT set to 3600 (1 hour?) .

Occasionally this Webjob changes to Aborted after 4 mins of running time. Under what circumstances would this happen?

Comment: Have you checked the logs for the WebJob and all of its triggered methods in the WebJobs Dashboard?

Comment: No, the logs are gone. I can't change the setting yet to preserve a longer job history. By the time I got to look, the max history had been exceeded. (This is why I am looking for reasons - I do see that Azure East US had issues round about the same time, though)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the code](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/8f595024cc1f2e30d085d71f39d5b432f8b75a06/Kudu.Core/Jobs/TriggeredJobsManager.cs#L180-L197), a job status is shown as aborted if its status file shows it as running, but it is not actually running.

This can happen if something abnormal happens. e.g. if Kudu suddenly dies without a chance to clean up.

As an aside, note that App Service has a 230 second limit for http requests that don't return data. However, I would not expect this to cause an Aborted state for the WebJob.

Comment: race condition? between line 180 and 186 status changes?

Comment: my guess this was due to timeouts when East US SQL had issues over 24th/25th. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: I think you're right about the theoretical race condition here, which could give an incorrect Aborted status during a very small window. But that we get corrected on the next status poll, so I doubt that's what you're up against. Good observation though :)

Comment: I can't check the job status history, but I do have an email based on Zapier integration that shows the status as Aborted. I wonder if the status change was somehow only transient. Actually, can I change the max history length (settings.job?) without the process restarting (and causing Abort statuses itself)? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can change it using `WEBJOBS_HISTORY_SIZE` ([wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#configuration-settings)), but that will cause a restart.